# Display highcharter plots wih hw_grid inside rmd R

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-highcharter

Can't display highcharter plots inside Rmd with `purrr::map` created tabs. 
It's works with tables and single plot, but not for `hw_grid`

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>"
)
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

```{r error=F, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)

highchart(height = 1)

lst <- gapminder %>% 
  select(continent, country) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  group_by(continent) %>% 
  slice(1:5)

data_pl <- gapminder %>% 
  mutate(across(c(country, continent), as.character)) %>% 
  inner_join(lst) %>% 
  group_by(continent, country) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(plot = purrr::pmap(list(data, continent, country), function(data, continent, country) {
    
    highchart() %>% 
      highcharter::hc_add_series(data, "spline", highcharter::hcaes(x = year, y = lifeExp), name = "lifeExp") %>%
      highcharter::hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", language = "eng", title = list(text = "Date")) %>%
      highcharter::hc_title(text = glue::glue('{continent}')) %>%
      highcharter::hc_subtitle(text = glue::glue('{country}')) %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_theme(highcharter::hc_theme_538()) 
  })) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(plot2 =  purrr::pmap(list(data, continent, country), function(data, continent, country) {
    
    highchart() %>% 
      highcharter::hc_add_series(data, "spline", highcharter::hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap), name = "gdpPercap") %>%
      highcharter::hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", language = "eng", title = list(text = "Date")) %>%
      highcharter::hc_title(text = glue::glue('{continent}')) %>%
      highcharter::hc_subtitle(text = glue::glue('{country}')) %>%
      highcharter::hc_add_theme(highcharter::hc_theme_538()) 
  })) 
```

#  {.tabset .tabset-pills}

```{r, results='asis', echo = F, warning= F, error= F, message=F}
invisible(
 data_pl$continent %>% unique() %>% sort() %>% 
  purrr::map(.,~{
  cat("##", ..1, '<br>', '\n')  # create tabs
  

  data_pl$country %>% unique() %>%  
      purrr::map(.,function(x){        # create platform
        
       p <-  data_pl %>%
            dplyr::filter(continent == ..1, country == x) %>%  
            dplyr::select(country, continent, plot, plot2)  %>% 
            pivot_longer(-c(country, continent)) %>% pull(value) %>% 
            hw_grid(ncol = 2, rowheight =  350)
         
       print(htmltools::tagList(p))
       
    })
  cat('\n', '<br>', '\n\n')
  })
)
```
````